# How to use Tensorflow addons' metrics correctly in functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an LSTM model to perform binary classification of human activities using multivariate smartphone sensor data. The two classes are imbalanced (1:50). Therefore I would like to use F1-score as a metric, but I saw that it was deprecated as a metric.

Before it was [best practice to use a callback function](https://medium.com/@thongonary/how-to-compute-f1-score-for-each-epoch-in-keras-a1acd17715a2) for the metric to ensure it was applied on the whole dataset, however, recently the [TensorFlow addons reintroduced the F1-Score](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score).

I now have a problem to apply this score to my functional API. Here is the code I am currently running:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow import kerasdef

create_model(n_neurons=150, learning_rate=0.01, activation="relu", loss="binary_crossentropy"):

   #create input layer and assign to current output layer
   input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])) 

   #add LSTM layer
   lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(n_neurons, activation=activation)(input_)

   #Output Layer
   output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(lstm)

   #Create Model
   model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_], outputs=[output])

   #Add optimizer
   optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, clipvalue=0.5)

   #Compile model
   model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=2, average="micro")])

   print(model.summary())

   return model

#Create the model
model = create_model()

#fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train, 
                epochs=300, 
                validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

If I use another value for the metric argument `average` (e.g., `average=None` or `average="macro"`) then I get an error message when fitting the model:

> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 1. Shapes are [ 2 ] and [ 1 ]. for 'AssignAddVariableOp' (op: 'AssignAddVariableOp') with input shapes: [ ], [ 1 ].

And if I use the value `average="micro"` I am not getting the error, but the F1-score is `0` throughout the learning process, while my loss decreases.

I believe I am still doing something wrong here. Can anybody provide an explanation for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Updated answer: The crucial bit is to import tf.keras, not keras. Then you can use e.g. tf.keras.metrics.Precision or tfa.metrics.F1Score without problems. See also [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/825#issuecomment-599262849).

Old answer:
The problem with tensorflow-addons is that the implementation of the current release (0.6.0) only counts exact matches, such that a comparison e.g. of 1 and 0.99 yields 0. Of course, this is practically useless in a neural network. This has been fixed in 0.7.0 (not yet released). You can install it as follows:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install tfa-nightly
```

and then use a threshold (everything below the threshold is counted as 0, otherwise as 1):

```
tfa.metrics.FBetaScore(num_classes=2,average="micro",threshold=0.9)
```

See also https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/490.
The problem with other values for `average` is discussed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/746.

Beware that there are two other problems that probably lead to useless results, see also https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/818:

1. the model uses binary classification, but f1-score in tfa assumes categorical classification with one-hot encoding
2. f1-score is called at each batch step at validation.

These problems should not appear when using the Keras metrics.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I will show how to use Adamw optimizer and F1_score using Tensorflow.

```
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate, decay_steps=100000, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True
)
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
f1 = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=2, average=None)

model=(..)
model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer=tfa.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=lr_schedule,weight_decay = 0.0001),
    metrics=["acc",'AUC',f1],
)
```